# How do I run a process and send it a SIGNAL while its running?

Tags: command-line, signals, process-management

I need to run a program xyz. It finishes execution in a few seconds.
It has some signal handling I need to test. From the shell or a bash script how do I execute the program and while it is executing send it a signal like `kill -14`.

Currently, the command I am trying, is

```
/usr/local/xyz input > some_file 2>&1 & PIDOS=$! && kill -14 $PIDOS
```

Does not seem to trigger the signal handling.

Comment: That code appears correct, so you will need to provide more detail, `strace` the process, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That command looks ok. Though when I tried that, it appears the command was too fast. It's as if my test script didn't have time to install the signal handler before it got shot.

A test script:

```
$ echo '$SIG{USR1} = sub { print "GOT SIGNAL\n" }; sleep 100' >  sigtest.pl
```

Shoot it immediately: <sub>(the sleep is there so the next prompt isn't immediately printed)</sub>

```
$ perl sigtest.pl & kill -USR1 $! ; sleep 1
[1] 8825
[1]+  User defined signal 1   perl sigtest.pl
```

It didn't print anything, but died to the signal. Let's give it some time:

```
perl sigtest.pl & ( sleep 0.5 ; kill -USR1 $! )
[1] 8827
GOT SIGNAL
[1]+  Done                    perl sigtest.pl
```

Now it worked, the signal handler fired. (the signal interrupted the `sleep`, so the script exited anyway).